# Why do I get a "no such file" error message from Rails' generate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Why do I get a "no such file" error message when I run this command?:

```
$ rails generate controller Pages home contact
c:/Users/Michele/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb::in 'require': no such file to load -- sprockets/railtie (LoadError)
        from c:/Users/Michele/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:8
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.11/ lib/rails commands.rd:15
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.11/ lib/rails commands.rd:15
        from script/rails:6:in 'require'
        from script/rails:6
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you don't have all Rails required libs installed.
try to run `gem install rails` command

or, maybe, you have borken rails app tree - try to create new rails app with `rails new my_app_name`